# Go to definition [Ctrl + Click] not working in VS code after change php version

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, editor, settings, go-to-definition

Go to Definition setting is ok , but not working.
not work on functions in php and js
anythink is missing? please tell me.

I go to preference setting and check all option about goToReferences.
i have no idea why is suddenly stop and not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't altered the goToReferences settings, did you install any plugins recently, if yes try uninstalling them and try again.
Check for any updates

If possible share the screenshot of goToReferences settings, so I can compare it with mine which is working fine with JS